# Implementing moving average with ReactiveX based on timestamps

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactivex

I'm using Rx.Net and I have Observable that emits time series points (double, timestamp). Every time new point arrives I want to calculate average value from lets say last 30 seconds. I think I need some kind of overlapping Window/Buffer not based on count but timestamp.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256557/trouble-implementing-a-sliding-window-in-rx) topic with SlidingWindow implementation, but I cannot figure out how to fit this to my problem.

EDIT:

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805392/rx-stateful-transform-of-sequence-e-g-exponential-moving-average?rq=1) I learned that I can use Scan operator and buffer my points, so basicly this solves the problem. But maybe there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Buffer` and `Window` look forward, you want something that looks back. `Scan` is the best starting point:

```
public static IObservable<List<T>> BackBuffer<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan ts)
{
    return BackBuffer(source, ts, Scheduler.Default);
}
public static IObservable<List<T>> BackBuffer<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan ts, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source
        .Timestamp()
        .Scan(new List<Timestamped<T>>(), (list, element) => list
            .Where(ti => scheduler.Now - ti.Timestamp <= ts)
            .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(element, 1))
            .ToList()
        )
        .Select(list => list.Select(t => t.Value).ToList());
}
```

Once you have `BackBuffer`, or something like it, then the rest becomes easy:

```
source
    .BackBuffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(70))
    .Select(list => list.Average())
    .Subscribe(average => Console.WriteLine(average));
```